# Simplifying MySQL query with multy union and stored values

Tags: mysql

Sample DB in dbfiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3pXTbTRFfM1mPCwETw4xRd/0

I several query part that list the items old and new values then creates a summary and average. Currently the query needs to be executed per every set variable and then the query it self.

Q1) Is it possible to set the `@min,@t and @n` within the select union query?

Q2) The average calculations apply decimal places to all values within the column. Is it possible to only apply the decimals to Average row?

Q3) Can the query be optimized?

Query:

```
set @min = 10;
set @t = -1;
set @n = -2;
select s.name,
    sum(case when v.type = 'total' then v.value end) as 'old',
    sum(case when v.type = 'new' then v.value end) as 'new'
from sample as s, `values` as v where s.id = v.sample_id and v.value >= @min
group by s.name
union select "Sum",
    @t:= sum(if (v.type = 'total', v.value, 0))  as 't' ,
    @n:= sum(if (v.type = 'new', v.value, 0))  as 'n'
from sample as s, `values` as v where s.id = v.sample_id and v.value >= @min
union select "Average", TRUNCATE(@n/(@t+@n)*100,2),0;
```

Result:

```
+---------+--------+------+
| name    | old    | new  |
+---------+--------+------+
| Canoon  | 100.00 |   40 |
| Epson   |  70.00 |   10 |
| Sum     | 170.00 |   50 |
| Average |  22.72 |    0 |
+---------+--------+------+
```

Comment: If you only wanted the sum, but not the overall average, then `WITH ROLLUP` would have been an option.  I"m not sure I see a way of generating your output without using a union -- somewhere.

Comment: A result set without a data set is like a stick without a lollipop. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: i have added a sample db into dbfiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3pXTbTRFfM1mPCwETw4xRd/0 let me know if this helps 
@Strawberry

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I do would like to see each individual Item + sum and average. I am just looking for a way to see if I can reduce the use of variables and make it more of a single query and not 4 queries.

Comment: You shouldn't need to set the @t and @n variables before the main query as they are not used before they are set. The @min variable can be set in the main query's first where clause: v.value >= (@min := 10)